# PHP Mysqli no errors, no querys

Tags: php, mysqli

I'm trying to use mysqli instead of mysql queries, and it's not working.
Mysqli:

```
$mysqli->connect($db1['host'], $db1['user'], $db1['password'], $db1['database']);
if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
        printf("Connect failed: %s\n", $mysqli->connect_error);
        exit();
    }
```

no errors. If I try this query:

```
if(isset($_POST['username']))
{
    $password = $_POST['p']; 

    $random_salt = hash('sha512', uniqid(mt_rand(1, mt_getrandmax()), true));

    $password = hash('sha512', $password.$random_salt);

    if ($insert_stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO members (username, email, password, salt) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)")) {    
       $insert_stmt->bind_param('ssss', $username, $email, $password, $random_salt); 

       $insert_stmt->execute();
    }
    echo "Success";
}
```

nothing is inserted, no errors with mysqli error. 
Table structure is correct, and it says success. I'm new to mysqli, I'm used to mysql. Is there something I've missed with error reporting?

Comment: Your echo Success is in wrong place. It should be inside that if

Comment: I added the Success in if, and "No success" in else. I get No success. This query owrks: mysqli_query($link", "Insert into members set username='a'");  <br/><br/> Something isn't working with the query and I can't seem to find how to output error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to do it like this way

```
$password = hash('sha512', $password.$random_salt);

$insert_stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO members (username, email, password, salt) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)");     
$insert_stmt->bind_param('ssss', $username, $email, $password, $random_salt); 

if($insert_stmt->execute())
{
    echo "Success";
}
```

Actually you are first checking the query and after that binding the params, because of that it was just displaying `Success`.

Comment: `<code>if(isset($_POST['username']))
{
 $password = $_POST['p']; 

 $random_salt = hash('sha512', uniqid(mt_rand(1, mt_getrandmax()), true));

$password = hash('sha512', $password.$random_salt);

$insert_stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO members (username, email, password, salt) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)");     
$insert_stmt->bind_param('ssss', $username, $email, $password, $random_salt); 

if($insert_stmt->execute())
{
    echo "Success";
}
else
{
 echo "Not success";
}
} /*<--- not success, this works */ mysqli_query($link", "Insert into members set username='a'"); </code>`

Answer (score 0):

Better try this, its from php manual

```
<?php
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "user", "password", "database");
if ($mysqli->connect_errno) 
{
echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: (" . $mysqli->connect_errno . ") " . $mysqli- >connect_error;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do the $stmt->execute(); in an if loop like this:

```
if ($stmt->execute()){

    $result = $stmt->affected_rows;

    if ($result) { echo "yay" } else { echo "boo"; }
}
else {
    printf("Execute error: %s", $stmt->error);
}
```